# Reload a image using ReactiveUI and WPF

Tags: wpf, image, reactiveui

I am trying to change a image in the UI running with WPF on runtime by changing the source of the image. Unfortunately the image is not changing. I found examples of using a Bitmap image to change the Image source, but with ReactiveUI I am not able to change the UriSource for the BitmapImage.

XAML code:

```
  <Image x:Name="button_image0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Source="someimage.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" />
```

view code:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.button_image0, v => v.button_image0).DisposeWith(d);
```

Viewmodel code:

```
[Reactive] public string button_image0 { get; set; }


//button pressed
button_image0 = "newimage.jpg";
```

I checked that the source of the image is changing, but the image displayed is not. Does someone know how to solve this with reactiveUI or knows a way around?

**Solution**
If anyone is having the same problem, it's a syntax error of your code. When changing the source of an image using reactiveUI the image is reloaded. This question and answer confused me [Reloading an image in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491383/reloading-an-image-in-wpf?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Is it possible you're not doing the update on the UI thread?  Use RxApp.MainThreadScheduler when you change your image.

Comment: How do I use the scheduler? I have tried `this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.button_image0).ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);`, but the image is not reloading when the source is changed.

Comment: That's the way to use it.  If a method has a parameter for the scheduler, use it there instead.  But the answer listed is probably your problem... I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

When binding you should include the control property as part of the expression. For example

```
ContentControl.Content

SizableControl.Width

Image.Source

TextBlock.Text
```

So if you bind to the "Source" property on the Image on the view. You also appear to have your notation of v and vm the wrong way around which might be adding to the confusion. The viewmodel is the 2nd expression, the view is the 3rd.

`this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.button_image0, vw => vw.button_image0.Source).DisposeWith(d);`

Comment: Where is the content control used? In the View or Viewmodel code?

Comment: in the view binding logic. added example of Image.Source, which is what i've put in the OneWayBind code sample :)